# Pure CSS responsive navbar check not working

Tags: html, css

i am new in the front end and learning it but today i am stuck, I am creating a full responsive navbar in css. i have checked this check button is working fine but why it is not showing me the nav menu. i don't why this #check:checked ~ .menu bar is not working. i know there i can find these codes easily but for now learning process i am asking to this question to community.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Startup Landing</title>
<style>body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root{
    --hero-background:#E5E5E5;
    --purple-clr:#8D448B;
    --fonts:'DM Sans', sans-serif;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: var(--fonts);
}
#check{
    display: none;
}
.bars{
    display: none !important;
}
.container{
    width:1400px;
    height: auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.hero-section{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.menu-bar{
    width:100%;
}
.menu-bar ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right:30px;
}
.menu-bar ul li{
    margin-right:50px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menu-bar ul li a{ 
   color: var(--purple-clr);
   font-weight: 500;
}
.head-button{
    margin-right:30px;
    border:2px solid var(--purple-clr);
    padding: 7px 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: var(--fonts);
    color: #8D448B;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.head-button:hover{
    background-color: var(--purple-clr);
    color:#fff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    body{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
   .bars{
    display: block !important;
    color: #8D448B;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }
   .logo{
    margin:15px 15px;
   }
   .menu-bar{
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    left: -100%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
   }
   .menu-bar ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: var(--purple-clr);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    

   }
   .menu-bar ul li{
    margin:20px
   }

   .menu-bar ul li a{
    color: #fff;;
    font-size:30px;
   }

   #check:checked ~ .menu-bar {
    left:0;
   }
}




 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="hero-section">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <nav class="menu-bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Advertise</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Conatct</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <label for="check">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-2x bars" onclick="toggleMenuOption"></i>
        </label>
        <div class="head-button">Register</div>
        </div>
    </header>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The css `~` is the general sibling selector. On MDN you can read that "*the general sibling combinator (~) separates two selectors and matches all iterations of the second element, that are following the first element (though not necessarily immediately), and are children of the same parent element.*"

So it allows you to select sibling that come **after** the element, but not before.

Your input comes after your menu, so you cannot use the general sibling in this case.

I have created a very simple example to show you how to use the `~` css selector. Here i just toggle the `display` of the nav element, but you could do whatever css change you want...

```css
.nav {
  display: none;
}

.input:checked ~ .nav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myInput" name="myInput" class="input">
<label for="myInput">Check me</label>

<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li>Item two</li>
    <li>Item three</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```